# File sharing not working, looking for alternatives

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-sharing

Windows 10 lost the ability to share files within your network. In either the fall or spring creators update they disabled SMB1.0. With that I lost the ability to use my main computer's hard drive as a game drive for the whole network and printing documents wirelessly.

I have researched this alot and tried all the powershell solutions, enabling SMB1 in programs and features but none of those fixed my issue. After updating to the verison that disabled file sharing, my computer still shows up in the network tab in file explorer but when i try opening it i wait for like 30 seconds to get
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnC20.png)

I have even made my own application in C# for transfering files over my local network, but that is only for transfering i have yet to implement printing and even if i do that i still lose the ability to use my computer as a game drive and play the game from another computer without transfering the whole game to my other computers

So the point of this whole thread. How can i get file sharing back, either by using some 3rd party software or in some way re-enabling file sharing in windows 10 (if its even possible).

Comment: Unfortunately, even if you somehow get SMB1 back, Windows 10 will eventually try to update itself to the modern version and disable it.  You may have a better time using another file share method.  Alternatively, you might install Windows 7 clean on another PC, and share out using your traditional SMB method from that.

Comment: Printing documents wirelessly - please update the question with the make/model of the printer you're using.  It may tolerate another file share method.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage It's not a wireless printing capable printer, i connected it to the computer and using windows sharing i was able to start printing just like if i were sitting at the computer it was plugged into

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to share files, you can try this.
1.Open File Explorer(Win + E)
2.Choose the folder you want to share.
3.Right-click on the folder, select **Give access to**, and click **the Specific people** option.

[image]

4.In the "Network access" wizard, use the drop-down menu, select the users you want to share the folder and its content:

(1)Individual user — If you select an existing account, the user must provide username and password to access the files, unless the user is logged with an account on the other device that features the same credentials.
(2)Everyone — Allows to share content with anyone in the network without the need to enter a password to access the files
[image]

5.Click the Add button.

6.Using the "Permission Level" drop-down menu, select how users will be accessing content in the shared folder:

(1)Read — Users can list and open files, but they're not allowed to modify or delete existing files and folder. Also, they won't be able to upload or create new files and folders.
(2)Read/Write — Users can list, open, modify, delete, upload, and create new files and folders.
(3)Remove — Restricts access to a user or group of users to the folder

7.Click the Share button.
After completing the steps, the wizard will give you the link that network users can use to access the folder and its content.

In this way, keep in mind that users will only be able to access the files if the device making the sharing is turned on and connected to the network.

Comment: What about folders, any way to share folders ?

Comment: Folders also can be shared in this way.

Comment: This still doesn't help me, my shared folders can't even be accesed from other pc. I can't even view them